# foreach loop issue with multiple names in a row

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a for each loop in which If the le specific day has a Holiday where `$holiday_result` has 1 array

```
var_dump($holiday_result);
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'closed' => string 'Closed' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Christmas 2017' (length=14)
      'bgcolor' => string '' (length=0)
      'color' => string '' (length=0)
      'startdate' => string '2017/02/17' (length=10)
      'enddate' => string '2017/02/17' (length=10)
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'closed' => string 'Closed' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Christmas 2017' (length=14)
      'bgcolor' => string '' (length=0)
      'color' => string '' (length=0)
      'startdate' => string '2017/02/17' (length=10)
      'enddate' => string '2017/02/17' (length=10)
```

that one condition I wish to display the Holiday after the another/last row ( hours row ) I have no idea how I write on this.

```
if ( empty( $holiday_result ) || ( empty( $holiday_result['closed'] ) ) ) {
    if ( 
       ( strtotime( $iva_curent_time ) >= strtotime( $time->open ) ) &&
       ( strtotime( $iva_curent_time ) <= strtotime( $time->close ) ) &&
       ( empty($todayfollowdate[$todaydate]['closed'])) ) {
        $out .= '<span class="hours-row"><span class="iva-bh-time">' . $ivbh_arr[ $day ] . '<span class="iva-bh-oc-dot iva_oc_close"></span></span>';
        if( $j == 0 ) {
            $out .= '<span class="iva_bh_holiday-hrs" ' . $extra . '>' . $holiday_name_var[ $followdate ]['name'] . '</span>';
        }
   } else {
        $out .= '<span class="hours-row"><span class="iva-bh-time">' . $ivbh_arr[ $day ] . '<span class="iva-bh-oc-dot iva_oc_close"></span></span>';
        if( $j == 0 ) {
            $out .= '<span class="iva_bh_holiday-hrs" ' . $extra . '>' . $holiday_name_var[ $followdate ]['name'] . '</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

**About Code Output:**

```
9:00 am-11:00 am
       Christmas
1:00 pm-11:00 pm
```

**What I'm Trying To Get Is after the loop of another hours row:**

```
9:00 am-11:00 am
1:00 pm-11:00 pm
       Christmas
```

Here is the current process how it looks like for better Idea of what am working on.
[image: Current Output]

Comment: the shared code do not help a lot to understand your problem, please share the full code related to this issue. Also I didn't notice any difference between the `$out` of the first condition and the `$out` of the second !

Comment: The code is way too long more than 1000+ lines. I will try to add more code and see.